# Parse the grouped data using StringGrouper to json

Tags: python, string, dataframe, group-by, data-science

I'm using StringGrouper to group the similar data together and I want to see the group data in json file how can I parse the data into json file
here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from string_grouper import match_strings, match_most_similar, \
group_similar_strings, compute_pairwise_similarities, \
StringGrouper

string_grouper = StringGrouper(data['name'],ignore_index=True,min_similarity=0.83)

string_grouper = string_grouper.fit()

data['deduplicated_name'] = string_grouper.get_groups()
```

the example of output right now:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWnvb.png

the  expected output in json format:

```
[
    [sql server 
        {
            “id”: 0
            “name”: “sql server ”
     
        },
{
            “id”: 1
            “name”: “sql server management”
        },
        //another name in the same group
    ], 
    [
       // another group
    ]
]
```

Comment: Can you please add some grouped text here ?

Answer (score 0):

> try using below code and modify it accordingly :

```
data[['id','name']].to_json(orient='records')
```

Comment: tried, but with this method ,it shows that data aint grouped